# Neural network for regression using Keras in R

Tags: r, keras

I am new to Keras and I am trying to build a neural network model for regression problem. my code is shown below

```
network <- keras_model_sequential() %>%
  layer_dense(units = 15, activation = "sigmoid", input_shape = c(50)) %>%
  layer_dense(units = 1)

summary(network)

network %>% compile(optimizer = optimizer_rmsprop(), loss = "mean_squared_error", metrics = c("accuracy"))

network %>% fit(train_features, train_target, epochs = 100)
```

when I summary the model, it looks like this:[image]
After I run the code, I got the following error:
[image]

I have no idea how to fix the error. Thanks for any help !

Comment: Try converting `train_features` to matrix

Comment: @HMK Thanks a lot. it works. However, there is another error appears, and I look up online. I need to reinstall the "Keras" package from github to resolve it.